# IntelliJ IDEA debugger super slow when loading classes

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I can easily start up my app running within intellij in debug mode. But when there is a class that needs to be loaded (e.g. JDBC driver, Jackson mapper, ...) it becomes extremely slow. If I stop execution, I can see it is in the middle of loading some inner class somewhere but that's it. Sometimes it does this after a 10-20s delay but sometimes even then it is not finished and I'm still waiting for my breakpoints to be hit.

For example, I have been waiting more than a minute for below call to finish.

How can I fix this slowness?

[image]

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544799. If you are debugging remotely, a connection can also affect it.